# Cannot add access policies in the Key vault in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have been trying to add access policies in the key vault but seeing the message as "The access configuration for this key vault is set to role-based access control. To add or manage your access policies, go to the Access control (IAM) page."

I have a key vault "Key Vault Administrator" access. what am I missing here?

Screenshot of access policy:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpBSv.png)

Screenshot of access configuration:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuCzq.png)

Many Thanks

I am trying to add access policies to the key vault

Answer (score 1):

Key Vault originally controlled access through access policies, but recently Microsoft has added role based access as an alternative which uses custom roles in the IAM section to secure the data plane. Key vaults can use one or the other but not both. The key vault you are trying to configure is set to use RBAC so you need to use the built in roles instead

[More here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Josh. 

I have granted myself the below RBAC role, but it doesn't give me access to add access policies 

Key Vault Administrator

Comment: If you have enabled RBAC-based access control on key vault then legacy access policies are disabled and you must do access control with RBAC roles like described in the linked documentation.